# Post HTML elements array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is the snapshoot of my form. The input values under LPO (1st column) are hidden, I just showed them here to show complete form.

[image]

if color_id (first left most inputbox) is 37 its DB value is `BB552` as displayed. And if its 3, the value of that color is `BB110`, but when its 0, it means a user has selected Custom and written a value by him self in the third row it is `FFBBBAA`.

I need to submit the form to PHP

The field names are as follows

```
color_id[] <-- Hidden input
order_id[] <-- Hidden input
subcolor_id[] <-- Select
subcolor_string[] <-- Input
material_id[] <-- Select
weight[] <-- input
```

When I post the form, in PHP

```
<?PHP

$count = count($_POST['weight']);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $color_id = $_POST['color_id'][$i];
    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'][$i];
    $material_id = $_POST['material_id'][$i];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'][$i];

    // i can count one post item and can iterate over all.

    if($color_id == 0){
       $color_id = $_POST['subcolor_id'][$i]; // this give me wrong result;
    }
    
}
```

So when 0 is there, admin approving this form, can leave it to custom or change the color back to some value from DB

I want to know what are the possibilities for getting the proper sub color values if first hidden input `color_id` has 0.

So far the one which I thought of is to add two more hidden fields in Sub Color columns to match their index, but this will require me to completely re-write the `del sub color` code

Is there any other way which can save me from doing lots of alterations to this form?

Comment: Do sub-categories have a specific number of items in them?

Comment: You mean to ask Sub Colors dropdown items? Yes they are coming from database, and every time color_id is 0, the dropdown is displayed.

Comment: I just want to ask, won't you get the sub color values in subcolor_string[] ?

Comment: Yes i can do that, but I need to update all the JS and forms, which I dont want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other option is to declare another iterator `$j` outside of the loop, starting at 0, and manually incrementing that iterator after you read a subcolor each time. Then it should always be the index of the next `subcolor_id` you need to read.

Comment: Hmm it sounds interesting, let me try. I will let you know

Answer (score 3):

as eds mentioned it totally makes sense.. u shud do this way

```
$j=0;
$count = count($_POST['weight']);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
$color_id = $_POST['color_id'][$i];
$order_id = $_POST['order_id'][$i];
$material_id = $_POST['material_id'][$i];
$weight = $_POST['weight'][$i];

// i can count one post item and can iterate over all.

if($color_id == 0){
   $color_id = $_POST['subcolor_id'][$j]; // this give me wrong result;
   $j++;
}

}
```

this shud solve your problem..